# Making Turbo Demo app work with local Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, hotwire-rails

I've set up a local Rails app that uses Turbo. I'm trying to shim [the Turbo Demo iOS app](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-ios) to display my local Rails app. Has anyone been able to do a similar thing?

I switched `Demo.current` to use the local address, but all the requests show the "Error loading page" screen, with no useful logs coming out of the Demo app.

The Rails app shows my base route as being attempted, with some form of persistence with retrying a `401` error. I changed the `SceneController` default URL to load a `/networks/all-people`, which requires an authorized user (via Devise) to hopefully see how the authentication logic would go. Below is the Rails output when running the Demo app:

```
Started GET "/networks/all-people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-21 19:50:26 -0500
Processing by NetworksController#all_people as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (Allocations: 256)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-21 19:50:26 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 218)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.7ms | Allocations: 1056)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 9.4ms | Allocations: 7318)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.8ms | Allocations: 7945)
```

Has anyone been able to shim the Demo app into working with a local Rails server? I'm entirely unsure of what's happening wrong here, or whether shimming is even a good idea here.

Turbo is being loaded in, as verified by the following event listener fires when visiting from my browser.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function(e) {
    console.log("TURBO LOADED");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that are needed to get Devise to work with Turbo.

**Add `app/controllers/turbo_controller`**:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class TurboController < ApplicationController
  class Responder < ActionController::Responder
    def to_turbo_stream
      controller.render(options.merge(formats: :html))
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
      raise e if get?

      if has_errors? && default_action
        render rendering_options.merge(formats: :html, status: :unprocessable_entity)
      else
        redirect_to navigation_location
      end
    end
  end

  self.responder = Responder
  respond_to :html, :turbo_stream
end
```

**Add `data: { turbo: "false" }` to your devise login form**:

```rb
# app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), data: { turbo: "false" }) do
```

**Update `config/initializers/devise.rb`**:

```rb
class TurboFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def skip_format?
    %w[html turbo_stream */*].include?(request_format.to_s)
  end
end

config.parent_controller = "TurboController"

config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :turbo_stream]

config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = TurboFailureApp
end
```

[Detailed explanation](https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-hotwire-turbo?autoplay=1) thanks to GoRails!