# I got "undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass" after upgrade from Turbolinks to Turbo with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-i18n

I have this controller

```
# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :redirect_admin_user, only: [:new]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]

  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected
    def redirect_admin_user
      if admin_signed_in?
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Please sign out of admin session"
      end
    end
end
```

I tried to log-in and got the error **"NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#create"** **"undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass"** at **I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)** from this controller

```
# app/controllers/application_controller
require 'action_text'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  Turbo::Redirection
  include Pagy::Backend
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  around_action :switch_locale
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  after_action :track_action

  def switch_locale(&action)
    if user_signed_in?
      locale = current_user.language
      I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
    else
      locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
    end
  end  

  protected

  def track_action
  ...
  end

  def set_locale
  ...
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
  ...
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    dashboard_path
    ahoy.authenticate(resource)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
  ...
  end

  def admin_signed_in?
  ...
  end

  def authenticate_admin!
  ...
  end

  helper_method :current_user?
  helper_method :admin_signed_in?
end
```

Application Trace

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `switch_locale'
```

Full Trace

```
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:264:in `handle_model'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:279:in `handle_model_call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:192:in `full_url_for'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:171:in `url_for'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:122:in `_process_options'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:201:in `_process_options'
actionview (6.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/pui/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:86:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
searchkick (4.5.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:217:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:240:in `default_render'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:172:in `to_html'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:165:in `respond'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:158:in `call'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:213:in `respond_with'
devise (4.8.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:23:in `create'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
i18n (1.8.10) lib/i18n.rb:314:in `with_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `switch_locale'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
react-rails (2.6.1) lib/react/rails/controller_lifecycle.rb:31:in `use_react_component_helper'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
ahoy_matey (3.2.0) lib/ahoy/controller.rb:45:in `set_ahoy_request_store'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.4) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.4) lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
searchkick (4.5.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:212:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/deflater.rb:44:in `call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:45:in `_call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:41:in `call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:45:in `_call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:41:in `call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:45:in `_call'
rack-tracker (1.12.1) lib/rack/tracker.rb:41:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
ahoy_matey (3.2.0) lib/ahoy/engine.rb:22:in `call_with_quiet_ahoy'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
rack-rewrite (1.5.1) lib/rack/rewrite.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
webpacker (6.0.0.rc.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.7.0) lib/rack/proxy.rb:63:in `call'
railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:248:in `call'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**resources:**
ruby '3.0.2'
rails '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'
rails-i18n '~> 6.0'
devise '~> 4.7', '>= 4.8'

I learn **ruby on rails** by **coding** can anyone advise how can I fix this error?

Comment: There are a few things needed to get Turbo to work with Devise. Try suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838902/7477016

Comment: @SarahMarie I added them already, I thought my issue occurred while trying to redirect to "dashboard_path" and check local from this "I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_path
  ahoy.authenticate(resource)
end
```

This method should be returning a string to where you should redirect the user and `ahoy.authenticate`instead returns a boolean. A less hacky way to tap into the flow of the Devise controllers is to simply call `super` with a block:

```
# @see https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition
module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_action :redirect_admin_user, only: [:new]
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]

    # note that your destroy method is completely superflouos - just use the super method

    def create
      # the parent controller yields after successfully signing a user in
      super do |resource|
        ahoy.authenticate(resource)
      end
    end

    protected
      def redirect_admin_user
        if admin_signed_in?
          redirect_to root_url, alert: "Please sign out of admin session"
        end
      end

      # remove the method in ApplicationController
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        dashboard_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works since almost all the Devise controllers yield at strategic points:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  # ....
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Its not completely obvious but `sign_in` will throw if the email or password is invalid so `yield resource if block_given?` is only reached if the user authenticates successfully.

Comment: I havent used Ahoy but this might be completely superflous also since "Ahoy automatically attaches the current_user to the visit. With Devise, it attaches the user even if they sign in after the visit starts.". https://github.com/ankane/ahoy